# Example of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Given that $A,B,C$ are subsets of $\Bbb R$ and $A\ne B\ne C$, also $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$. And $A$ is measurable, $B$ is closed, $C$ is compact and $m(A)=m(C)>0$.

Is that any example to satisfy the above conditions?

Since $m(A)=m(C)$, I know that $\lambda(A)=\lambda(C)$.

The sets $A,B,C$ should like this interval $(x,y)$. But I don't know which is open and closed interval.

Comment: Try $A=(0,1)$, $B=[0,1]$ and $C=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$.

Comment: What are $m$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: So C = [0,1] ∪ {2} ⊆ (-2,3)  and λ(C) = λ((-2,3)) - λ( (-2,3)\[0,1] ∪ {2}) = 5-4 =1?